# Read-Only Product Backend attribute

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, magento-1, backend

I would like to create an attribute read only however it look it is not possible.

I have tried to pass to addAttribute() `'disabled' =>true` or `'readonly' => true` 
with out any success.
I have found out some suggestion about using `setLockedAttributes()` but for some reason it is not working

**Reference:**
`Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract::serialize($attributes = array(), $valueSeparator='=', $fieldSeparator=' ', $quote='"')`

Comment: The question was answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384120/magento-read-only-and-hidden-product-attributes

Comment: This solution is not working. (setLockedAttributes)

Comment: it is not `setLockedAttribute`, it is `lockAttribute` :-)

Comment: Tim! You smiled! :-D

Comment: thanks guys ... I will check it out an update the thread

Comment: We are waiting for an update :D

Comment: :) It passed a lot of time, I'm accepting @philwinkle but to be honest I cannot remember what I did here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the referenced SO article - I tried and this indeed works on 1.6CE and 1.7CE / 1.12EE. I haven't tried on 1.8/1.13 as of yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384120/magento-read-only-and-hidden-product-attributes

> OK, it looks like it can be done after all. After adding an observer
>   for the `catalog_product_load_after` event, the `lockAttribute` method of
>   the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` class may be used to make a product
>   attribute read-only. Here is the code for the observer method:

```
public function lockAttributes($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct();
    $product->lockAttribute('attribute_code');
}
```

Comment: I'd go with the `catalog_product_edit_action` event instead (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7874345/394589), if the locking needs to be done only when editing ofc.

Answer (score 8):

If it is enough for you to make it not editable in product management, use the frontend input type `label`, which replaces the form input with plain text:

```
addAttribute($entity, $code, array(
    ...
    'input' => 'label',
    ...
));
```

Note that this will not prevent saving the attribute through API or manipulated POST request. To make it secure, additionally use `lockAttribute()` [as suggested above](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2982/243).

Also it only looks good for text type attributes, for other types, again, fall back to `lockAttributes` or extend the "label" type.

Comment: this works only if the attribute is text type, for boolean you need lockattribute()

Comment: Good point, @Fra, thanks! I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 1.9.4.1 even for text attributes

Answer (score 3):

To make this fixed, you can alternatively use an input renderer for this.
The downside is, you would have to do this for each input type and set this via setup for each attribute.

To do so, use the **input_renderer** key when using *addAttribute* an attribute or **frontend_input_renderer** when using *updateAttribute*.
Example:

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'yourattribute', array(
// ...
// won't be used actually as you use a custom renderer (constant equals to text), but I'm not sure what omitting this will have as effect..
    'input' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_TEXT,
    'input_renderer' => 'yourns_yourmodule/adminhtml_product_helper_form_disabledText',
    'frontend_class' => 'disabled',
    'note' => 'This field is disabled',
// ...
));
```

Then with your class  `Yourns_Yourmodule_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Helper_Form_DisabledText` extend the input class you would actually use. For a text field it would be `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text`.
For selects it would be `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select` and so on.

Now add your code like this to disable the attribute, overwriting the `getHtml` method, setting the attribute and returning the actual HTML code for the input field:

```
public function getHtml()
{
    // Set disabled
    $this->setReadonly(true, true);
    return parent::getHtml();
}
```

The method can be found in *lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php* which will be inherited by all form input element fields, so it should alaways be available.

```
/**
 * Disable elements
 *
 * @param boolean $readonly
 * @param boolean $useDisabled
 * @return Varien_Data_Form_Abstract
 */
public function setReadonly($readonly, $useDisabled = false)
{
    if ($useDisabled) {
        $this->setDisabled($readonly);
        $this->setData('readonly_disabled', $readonly);
    } else {
        $this->setData('readonly', $readonly);
    }
    foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
        $element->setReadonly($readonly, $useDisabled);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

It's probably senseful to include the *disabled* class in the attribute setup like shown above to visualize the denied input possibility.
You can probably also use `$this->addClass('disabled')` in the method, I did not try this yet.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2982/46249) ... full downloadable extension here:

- used `lockAttributes()` code from above
- changed event to `catalog_product_edit_action`
- added (storeview based) system configuration

https://github.com/sreichel/magento-StackExchange_LockAttributes