# Make Magento 2 Product Attribute Read-Only

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, eav

In Magento 1, we used the `lockAttribute($attributeCode)` method from a `catalog_product_edit_action` observer, and it prevented the admin user from editing that particular attribute. See [Read-Only Product Backend attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/784/read-only-product-backend-attribute).

Magento 2 has the same `lockAttribute` method in `Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel`. However, the UI for the attribute is no different after calling this method.

I also tried it on `catalog_product_save_before`, and it still allowed me to apply a new value to the attribute.

**Vendor/Module/Observer/Lock.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class Lock implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Observer to catalog_product_save_before to lock attributes.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $product->lockAttribute('my_custom_attribute');
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- <event name="catalog_product_save_before"> -->
    <event name="catalog_product_edit_action">
        <observer name="test_lock_attributes" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Lock"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 15):

Starting from 2.1 Magento uses UI component to build product admin form.
Thus, it should be customized as suggested in the [manual](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html).

In particular, your task could be accomplished with *modifier* approach.

Create DI file under `YourVendor/YourModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` with the content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sap_product" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Attributes</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Create modifier class:

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Attributes extends AbstractModifier
{
    private $arrayManager;

    public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager)
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $attribute = '...'; // Your attribute code goes here

        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath($attribute, $meta, null, 'children');
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
            "{$path}/arguments/data/config/disabled",
            $meta,
            true
        );
        return $meta;
    }
}
```

`modifyMeta` method allows you to dynamically customise UI component's configuration. Here we find the attribute element configuration and update it's `disabled` flag to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

**etc\adminhtml\events.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_load_after">
      <observer name="product_lock_attributes" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Lock"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer\Lock.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 
class Lock implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $product->lockAttribute('attribute_code');
     }
}
```