# Custom non-editable product attributes not visible on backend grid

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom, backend

I am edding and filling some attributes programmatically 
with `addAttribute` in magento 1.9.3

I don't want them to be editable, so I set `"input" => "label"`, but when I do it I can't select the attributes for the product grid to show on backend **("Manage Products" -> "Grid Attribute Columns" -> "Attribute Columns")**. For those for which I set `"input" => "text"` I can see them in the selection.

How can I make the non-editable custom-attributes visible on the backend product grid? 
Has anyone dealt with this (`input=label`)? 
Should I modify the backend code?

This question is different from [Read-Only Product Backend attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/784/read-only-product-backend-attribute) because in my case the attributes are visible in the products tab and everything seems fine from the first glance. Later on it looks like some inconvenience. So I would not just address it to the question about not-working readonly attributes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Magento docs (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.types.html), the following default types are acceptable for product attributes:

1. text
2. List item
3. textarea
4. date
5. boolean [yes/no]
6. multiselect
7. select
8. price
9. media_image

Setting the input type to `label` will not work, but it sounds like you can lock an attribute by setting it as **Read Only** after you create it.

```
public function lockAttributes($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct();
    $product->lockAttribute('attribute_code');
}
```

Credit to this post: [Magento read-only and hidden product attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6437906/1830601)

**Note:**

> Since the `catalog_product_load_after` event is dispatched for every product load, the attributes supplied in the `lock_attributes` method are locked after every product load. This could have unexpected results: it is not possible to change the value of the attributes in the lock_attributes method without explicitly unlocking them.
>
> Instead of using the `catalog_product_load_after` event, it suffices to add an observer for the `catalog_product_edit_action` event: this event is dispatched only when editing a product in the admin interface.