# Allow edit product attributes on user permission

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, permissions, user-roles, admin-user

I need my users not able to edit attributes, but they can view the attributes.

Comment: best way is to create separate user and  role and not to assign editing attributes to that user.....

Comment: Hey, can you please accept an anwer, if you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about attribute when editing products read here: 
[Read-Only Product Backend attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/784/read-only-product-backend-attribute/79465)

---

**Edit:** to make based on usesr permissions you can try this:

1. create custom module
2. add new ACL permission in `adminhtml.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <acl>
           <resources>
               <admin>
                   <children>
                        <catalog>
                           <children>
                               <products>
                                   <children>
                                       <edit_locked_attributes translate="title" module="stackexchange_lockattributes">
                                           <title>Edit Locked Attributes</title>
                                           <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                       </edit_locked_attributes>
                                   </children>
                               </products>
                           </children>
                       </catalog>
                   </children>
               </admin>
           </resources>
       </acl>
   </config>
   ```
3. Add an observer to `config.xml`

   ```
   <events>
       <catalog_product_edit_action>
           <observers>
               <lock_attributes>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>stackexchange_lockattributes/observer</class>
                   <method>lockProductAttributes</method>
               </lock_attributes>
           </observers>
       </catalog_product_edit_action>
   </events>
   ```
4. `Observer.php`

   ```
   class StackExchange_LockAttributes_Model_Observer
   {
       /**
        * Make product attributes uneditable
        *
        * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
        * @return void
        */
       public function lockProductAttributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           if (!$this->_isAllowed()) {
               /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
               $product = $observer->getProduct();
               $attributes = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/backend/lock_attributes', $product->getStoreId()));
               if (count($attributes)) {
                   foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode) {
                       $product->lockAttribute($attributeCode);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       /**
        * Check admin permissions for locked attributes
        */
       protected function _isAllowed()
       {
           return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/products/edit_locked_attributes');
       }
   }
   ```
5. add config section to make it a bit flexible ...

---

<sup>Download: https://github.com/sreichel/magento-StackExchange_LockAttributes</sup>

Comment: will it make attribute readonly for a particular user role?

Comment: No, its not role based.

Comment: I guess OP's question is for edit attribute and not for editing product

Comment: Not tried, but I guess you can use `catalog_product_attribute_edit_action` then.

Comment: @sv3n  where i can lock the attribute?

Comment: @zus there is a new config option: system -> config -> catalog -> backend -> lock attributes.

Comment: Admin able to edit,  admin users only not able to edit. how can I change the condition?

Comment: @zus update answer, so you can give permissions based on user role.

Comment: @sv3n could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215022/57334

Comment: @zus can you please give some feedback here first? Those this answer your question?

Comment: @sv3n We declare only selected field what admin user going to edit. I just want to know is possible or not, in future i will use what you suggest, and i +1 vote for you. If i accepted answer without any production someone asking how made by you, that's what i am not accepted answer. But your help is really valuable for me in every time thanks for that. Really i lean lot from your posts, once again thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks @sv3n you helped me alot! Great work!  (I know that "thank you" answers are not wanted, but I had to;) you can delete it if you want

Comment: @Zus Found some time to test it?

Answer (score 2):

You can write observer for admin edit action of attributes and allow to save only if the current admin login user is "Superadmin".

You can use:

> catalog_product_attribute_update_before

event for this purpose.

Just go through Magento docs regarding events and observers.